# How do you POST a json list of objects using the jersey REST Webtarget API? - getting error MessageBodyWriter not found

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I can send a single object fine with the following code:

```
        Entity<User> body = Entity.json(user);
        Response response = webTarget.path("/singleuser")
          .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .post(body);
```

however, this does not work:

```
        Entity<List<User>> body = Entity.json(users);


        Response response = webTarget
                .path("/multipleusers")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(body);
```

I get the following error:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Try to use `Entity.json(new GenericEntity<List<User>>(users){})`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha that worked, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this will work, but you can try array instead of list.

```
Entity<User[]> body = Entity.json(users);
        Response response = webTarget
                .path("/multipleusers")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(body);
```